# How can I find the index of an element inside of my List<int>?

Tags: c#, list

Here's what I have:

```
public int FindItem(int elementoABuscar)
{
    int indice = vectorNumeros.FindIndex(0, asd);
    return indice;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out the second part of the FindIndex method.

How would I find the index of elementoABuscar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use [`List<int>.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx):

```
int indice = vectorNumeros.IndexOf(elementoABuscar);
```

[`FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9(v=VS.90).aspx) is used to find an item which matches a particular predicate - you don't need it here, if you're just trying to find an element directly.

Note that if your list is sorted, you could also use [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839(v=VS.90).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `list.IndexOf(object)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int indice = vectorNumeros.IndexOf(elementoABuscar);
```

[msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx)